# How to serve one AjaxFileHandler.ashx for multimple file upload controls

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am wokring with file upload functionality. I have 2 types of images and 1 type of html upload with different location.

For example,

1. I have a home picture upload control to save all files somewhere in /Home folder
2. I have a Office picture upload control to save all files somewhere in /Office folder
3. If I have html file upload control, then I want to put all pages at Html folder somewhere

so for this,

```
$("#imgHomePicture").fileupload({
    url: 'AjaxFileHandler.ashx',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    alet("upload done");
    e.preventDefault();
}).on('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {
    var percentVal = '0%';
    var percentVal = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('.bar').css(
        'width',
        percentVal + '%'
    );
    $('.percent').html(percentVal + '%');
}).on('fileuploadcomplete', function (e, data) {
    alert("Upload complete");
});

$("#imgOfficePicture").fileupload({
    url: 'AjaxFileHandler.ashx',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
......

$("#htmlUpload").fileupload({
    url: 'AjaxFileHandler.ashx',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    async: true,

.....
```

C# code:

```
public class AjaxFileHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // here I want to know that, the request coming from Home /office or html file upload, based on this I can create the path and save file.
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Query string arguments? AjaxFileHandler.ashx?source=picture, AjaxFileHandler.ashx?source=html

Comment: are you sure about this?

Comment: Nope, but its what I might try as quick win to get some identifier in there. Or have a different handler for each? Also you might get a content-type/mime-type identifier which may help.  I think word docs are something like application/x something or other.